# AWS Lambda: “Process exited before completing request”

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, web-scraping

I ran grunt deploy, uploaded the zip file to the lambda function and tested it. The same error keeps turning up. The lambda function is being used for my facebook chatbot using aws lex.

So the error  "Process exited before completing request" keeps popping up. 
I'm trying to do webcrawling, but this is the first time I use node js. What am I doing wrong here? There must be something wrong with request function..

```
'use strict';
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var moment = require('moment');
var stringbuilder = require('stringbuilder');
var menus = [];

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  var diningHall = event.currentIntent.slots.diningHallName;

  request(event.webpage, function (err, response, body) {
    if (err) context.done();
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('menu-item-title').each(function (i, elem) {
      menus[i] = $(this).text();
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
      stringbuilder.append(menus[i] + "\n");
    }
});

callback(null, {
  "dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText",
      "content": "Here is what is being offered in the " + diningHall + "\n" + stringbuilder
    }

  }
});
};
```

Comment: I tried doing grunt deploy, uploaded the zip file to the lambda function and tested it. The same error keeps turning up. I wish there were someone that could help me.The lambda function is being used for my facebook chatbot using aws lex..

Comment: Thanks. I'm not used to posting questions here.